# How to handle 403 forbidden error in docker container?

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

I have been running an application in docker container in windows 10. git for the application is 
https://github.com/CogStack/MedCATtrainer
There are multiple places where I am uploading static files which is subsequently modified by the application. AFter the modification when I am trying to download the file. It is throwing the above error.

http://localhost:8001/media/core_snomed_cdb_pjW1Zmf.dat 
when i have the above url it should allow me to download the file.
The docker and nginx configuration files are the above link.

I am fairly inexperienced not able to find out how to debug this.

Comment: Please paste relevant code sections in the question so we can help you better.

Comment: Docker log says below.172.18.0.1 - - [26/May/2020:11:18:44 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 432 "http://localhost:8001/media/core_snomed_cdb_pjW1Zmf.dat" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"

Comment: The entire code is available in above git.

Comment: Resolved the issue. Basically a file permission issue. Open the command prompt from the Docker windows dashboard. Use the correct container. Search for the correct file and then change permission by chmod 777 filename.dat.